# PhantomJS blocked by sucuri cloudproxy

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

When I try to load this page I get blocked and I get a javascript string that I must solve in order to be redirected. For some reason, PhantomJS cannot solve this javascript redirect. Does anyone know any way around this?

This is the url:

```
http://www.electronicsforless.ca/search/results.html?search_in_description=1&keyword=samsung+hdtv
```

This is my phantom code:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
var args = system.args;

var page = webPage.create();

var url = args[1];


page.open(url, function(status) {
    var content = page.content;
    fs.write('test.txt', content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

This is the output:

```
<html><head><title>You are being redirected...</title>
<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>
<script>var s={},u,c,U,r,i,l=0,a,e=eval,w=String.fromCharCode,sucuri_cloudproxy_js='',S='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';L=S.length;U=0;r='';var A='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';for(u=0;u<64;u++){s[A.charAt(u)]=u;}for(i=0;i<L;i++){c=s[S.charAt(i)];U=(U<<6)+c;l+=6;while(l>=8){((a=(U>>>(l-=8))&0xff)||(i<(L-2)))&&(r+=w(a));}}e(r);</script></head></html>
```

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm using version 2.1.1. After adding your code I'm seeing Error code: 5. Description: Operation cancelled